# Help understanding alternate variance formula

Tags: variance

The definition of variance I’m comfortable with is

$$\Sigma_s{(x_i -\bar{x})(y_i -\bar{y})p(x_i,y_i)}$$

But I saw one that looks like this and I’m struggling to see how they’re equivalent.

$$\Sigma_x \Sigma_y (x+y)^2 P_{XY}-(E(x+y))^2$$ [source](http://www.milefoot.com/math/stat/rv-sums.htm)

Comment: The first item you have listed is the covariance of $x_i$ and $y_i$.  The second is the variance of $x+y$ (i.e. $Var(x+y)$).  Does that help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first item you have listed is the covariance of $x_i$ and $y_i$.  The second formula you have listed is the variance of $x+y$ (i.e. $Var(x+y)$).

To see this, note that we can write $Cov(X,Y)$ as:

\begin{eqnarray*}
{Cov(X,Y)} & = & E(XY)-E(X)(EY)\\
 & = & \sum x_{i}y_{i}p_{XY}(x_{i},y_{i})-\sum x_{i}p(x_{i},y_{i})\sum y_{i}p_{XY}(x_{i},y_{i})\\
 & = & p_{XY}(x_{i},y_{i})\left(\sum x_{i}y_{i}-\sum x_{i}\sum y_{i}\right)\\
 & = & \sum(x_{i}-\bar{x})(y_{i}-\bar{y})p_{XY}(x_{i}y_{i})
\end{eqnarray*}

The second formula you have listed is derived on the [source you hyperlinked to](http://www.milefoot.com/math/stat/rv-sums.htm) under the Variance Section.

The two formulas are not equivalent.